# In alternative hypothesis in $t$-test, why is $t_{1-α}$ used as the criteria $t$ for rejection and not $t_α$?

Tags: statistics

In general common rejection region of t-test, there are three possible alternative hypotheses and rejection regions for the one-sample t-test:

1. For alternative hypothesis $H_1: μ1 ≠ μ2$, the rejection region is $|T| > t_{α/2},ν$
2. For alternative hypothesis $H_1: μ1 > μ2$, the rejection region is $|T| > t_{1-α},ν$
3. For alternative hypothesis $H_1: μ1 < μ2$, the rejection region is $|T| > t_{α},ν$

my question is, WHY for alternative hypothesis $(2) H_1: μ1 > μ2$  the criteria $t$ for rejection is using **$t_{1-α}$** than **$t_α$**????

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you want the rejection probability to be the same ($\alpha$) in each case, and you use the $(1-\alpha)$ percentile to reject to the right, and the $\alpha$ percentile to reject to the left. I think you haven't quite got your criteria quite right, so I'm putting what I think are the correct criteria as well.

**1.** $\;\;|T| > t_{1-α/2}$, which is equivalent to $T > t_{1-α/2}$ or $-T > t_{1-α/2}$. When you multiply $-T > t_{α/2}$ by $-1$ you get $T < t_{α/2}$ because of the symmetry of the t distribution.

Rejection probability is $\alpha/2$ to the left and $\alpha/2$ to the right. Total $\alpha$.

Example: $\alpha=5$%. Reject when $T$ is less than the 2.5th percentile or greater than the 97.5th percentile of $t(\nu)$.

**2.** $\;\;T > t_{1-α}$

Rejection probability is $\alpha$ to the right.

Example: $\alpha=5$%. Reject when $T$ is greater than the 95th percentile of $t(\nu)$.

**3.** $\;\;T < t_{α}$

Rejection probability is $\alpha$ to the left.

Example: $\alpha=5$%. Reject when $T$ is less than the 5th percentile of $t(\nu)$.